# How can I monitor the media sense for an Ethernet interface in c#

Tags: c#, windows-10, tcp, ethernet, wifi

I am using W10 v1809 Enterprise on an HP Elitebook 850 G4

I have looked around and tried:

```
NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged
```

but that only triggers when I lose connectivity, completely.  If I plug in an Ethernet cable, I want to disable the WiFi adapter but there appears to be no way that I can do that (without monitoring the mediasense on the Ethernet interface) since I don't lose connectivity. I just GAIN another route.

I am basically trying to make up for HP's shortcomings in their LAN/WLAN switching but I am stymied about how to make the switch based on the Ethernet Interface being active/IP enabled and functional.

I welcome any insight people might have.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you may check for [NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.networkaddresschanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) and then decide whether disable or enable WiFi.

Comment: @vasily.sib - that's got some really nice potential.  I'll have a look a bit later or tomorrow morning.  Cheers!

Comment: @vasily.sib - Preliminary testing indicates that this doesn't live up to the hope :(